# Error: SQLiteException: no such column : comentarios (code 1):, while compiling

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy intentando acceder a la base de datos en local para obtener la lista de todas las jugadas y obtengo el error SQLiteException: no such column : comentarios (code 1):, while compiling

He estado usando el debugger y el error salta justo en el momento en el que intenta crear el cursor:

**Metodo que hace la query**

```
public List<Jugada> getAllJugadas() {
    // Lista que almacenara el resultado
    List<Jugada> jugadasList = new ArrayList<Jugada>();
    //hacemos una query porque queremos devolver un cursor
    Cursor cursor = db.query(helper.TABLE_NAME, columnas,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        final Jugada jugada = new Jugada();
        jugada.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
        jugada.setImagen(cursor.getString(2));
        jugada.setComentarios(cursor.getString(3));

        jugadasList.add(jugada);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    // Una vez obtenidos todos los datos y cerrado el cursor, devolvemos la
    // lista.
    return jugadasList;
}
```

**Clase que crea la BD**

```
    public class BDHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jugadas.db";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "jugadas";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOMBRE = "nombre";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMGEN = "imagen";
    public static final String COLUMN_COMENTARIOS = "comentarios";


    /** Script para la creación de la base de datos **/
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + "( " +
            COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            COLUMN_NOMBRE + " text not null, " +
            COLUMN_IMGEN + " text not null, " +
            COLUMN_COMENTARIOS + " text not null )";

    /** Script para la eliminación de la base de datos **/
    private static final String DATABASE_DROP = "drop table if exists " + TABLE_NAME;

    public BDHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        try {
            cargaJugadas(db);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void cargaJugadas(SQLiteDatabase db) throws IOException {
        File archivo = new File("jugadas_ataque.txt");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String linea;
        String expr;
        while((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
            String[] campos = linea.split(",");
            expr = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + campos[0] + ", " + campos[1] + ", " + campos[2];
            db.execSQL(expr);
        }
        reader.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_DROP);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

He mirado muchas preguntas del estilo e intentando las soluciones de los demás no he conseguido que funciones. ¿Alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: que contiene tu variable `columnas` ?  pon ese código, seria de mas ayuda. Y coloca el Log de la excepción que te lanza para ver mas detalles de donde esta sucediendo el problema.

Comment: Para que sirve tu variable/parámetro "Columnas"?, deberías de ser un poco mas especifico

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Sergio., te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso el mensaje de error indica que no se tiene la columna `comentarios` en la tabla consultada :

> Error: SQLiteException: no such column : comentarios (code 1):, while
>   compiling

El query que usas para crear la base de datos es correcto, incluso la nomenclatura de los campos:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "jugadas";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NOMBRE = "nombre";
public static final String COLUMN_IMGEN = "imagen";
public static final String COLUMN_COMENTARIOS = "comentarios";


/** Script para la creación de la base de datos **/
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " + TABLE_NAME + "( " +
        COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        COLUMN_NOMBRE + " text not null, " +
        COLUMN_IMGEN + " text not null, " +
        COLUMN_COMENTARIOS + " text not null )";
```

> Si es correcto ¿Que puede estar ocurriendo aquí?

Seguramente se creo una tabla con datos incorrectos, esta estructura de tabla no se puede modificar, claro al menos que realices una actualización de la aplicación, esta actualización llama al método:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_DROP);
    this.onCreate(db);
}
```

**La solución que te sugiero es eliminar el caché de tu aplicación, o eliminar la aplicación y volver a subirla a tu dispositivo.** Esto creará la estructura correcta de tu tabla.

Comment: Al desinstalar la app y volver a instalarla no me ha dado ningún error. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente Sergio, lo que sucede es que creo nuevamente la BD y la tabla con la estructura correcta, incluyendo el campo "comentarios", saludos!